# Add / remove class to all elements

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

this time I am working with the orders table.

I have that table:
[image]

```
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="selectAll"></th>
        <th>Zamówienie</th>
        <th>Przewoźnik</th>
        <th>Numer listu</th>
        <th>Waga</th>
        <th>Akcje</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="searchable">
      <tr id="701" class="" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="lp text-center vert-align">1.</td>
        <td class="reference">Sample order 3</td>
        <td class="przewoznik">UPS</td>
        <td class="numer_listu">BB0000001</td>
        <td class="waga">150</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info action action-editOrder btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edytuj zamówienie">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"</span>  
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="700" class="success" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="lp text-center vert-align">2.</td>
        <td class="reference">Sample order 2</td>
        <td class="przewoznik">DPD</td>
        <td class="numer_listu"></td>
        <td class="waga">0</td>
        <td style="text-align: center;">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-info action action-editOrder btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edytuj zamówienie">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
          </button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr id="699" class="" style="display: table-row;">
        <td class="lp text-center vert-align">3.</td>
        <td class="reference">Sample order</td>
        <td class="przewoznik">DPD</td>
         <td class="numer_listu">RR0000001</td>
         <td class="waga">0</td>
         <td style="text-align: center;">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-info action action-editOrder btn-xs" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Edytuj zamówienie">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           </button>
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
             <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" aria-hidden="true"></span>
           </button>
         </td>
       </tr>
     </tbody>
 </table>
```

And I would like select rows by clicking:
[image]

```
$("body").on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('success');
});
```

And select / deselect all rows by clicking:
[image]

```
$("body").on('click', 'table th.selectAll', function(event){
    $('tbody tr').toggleClass('success');
});
```

But problem is when I want to select all in case when I have already one selected. Then it inverts my selection:
[image]

I expect select and deselect all items, even if some are selected.

Comment: Obviously it will toggle the one which was selected before. Do removeClass first and then do toggleClass for all the rows.

Comment: Ok its simple, but... it doesnt work in case of deselect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this...(if you are using jQuery right)

```
    $("body").on('click', 'table th.selectAll', function(event){
    if($(this).hasClass("selected"){
       $('tbody tr').removeClass('success');
       $(this).removeClass("selected");
    }
    else{
       $('tbody tr').addClass('success');
       $(this).addClass("selected");
    }
    });
```

Adding a class 'selected' to th element when all rows are selected and vice versa.

Comment: It's pretty close, but in this doesnt work in case when I have manually select few or alll records and I have selected class on `th.selectAll`.

Comment: I understood it won't when all rows are selected. but can't understand why it doesn't work when few rows are selected.

Comment: Because when I selected manually few rows and `th.selectAll` has class `selected` and when I click, then function remove class `succes` from all items. But maybe it has sense and I overthinking ;p

Comment: Have you tried the solution in your code? it should work.

Comment: Yes of course, it works. But I thing about that solution: when some one isn't `success` button `selectAll` always selected all. But when all are selected, then button deselect all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103958/discussion-between-savaratkar-and-user3041764).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to thank you for your time Savaratkar. With your help I was able to finally get to this version:

```
$("body").on('click', 'tbody tr', function(event){
    $(this).toggleClass('success unselected');
});

$("body").on('click', 'table th.selectAll', function(event){
    if($( "table" ).find( "tr.unselected" ).length > 0) {
        $('tbody tr').removeClass('unselected').addClass('success');
    } else {
        $('tbody tr').removeClass('success').addClass('unselected');
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ar5h3u0/3/

This solution is satisfying for me.